# How do I implement protected client routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, next.js

#### Hey there! :)

I am using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) to build a college dashboard that incorporates Teacher, Student and Admin dashboards.

I have created a common Home page from where you can choose to login/signup as any of those. Since we have 3 different type of clients so we have these multiple dynamic routes for Authentication

### What I want ?

I want the actual dashboard routes to be well protected if the client is not Authenticated i.e. *the client should not be able to access any of those routes if he/she is not Logged in.*

Also, If they did try to do the same they should get redirected to the **Home** page from where they can choose to further login/signup as a Teacher, Student or Admin.

### What is the issue ?

I have a `user object` (*it is null if no user is loggen in*) using which I check whether a person is authenticated or not. So in my **custom _app** I am checking the same but when the user is not logged in I can redirect it to only a specific route say Home '/' which means if a person opted for say login as student he/she will again be redirected to the Home page which should not happen instead all the authentication related routes should be accessible.

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './index';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Layout from "../Components/Authentication/Layout";
import Layout2 from '../Components/SD_Comps/Layout';
import Layout3 from '../Components/EP_Comps/Layout';
import { useUser } from '../lib/hooks';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import '../style.scss';
import '../node_modules/hover.css/css/hover-min.css';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user] = useUser();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"></link>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
      </Head>

      {user ? (router.pathname.startsWith('/StudentDash') ? <Layout2><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout2> :
        (router.pathname.startsWith('/ExamPortal/') ? <Layout3><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout3> :
          <Layout><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout>)) : <Layout><Home /> </Layout>}

    </>
  )
}
```

### The Big Question !

*How can I make specific routes accessible while keeping others protected when user is not Authenticated ?*

Comment: make AppRoute and NonAuthRoute that have all logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation you're sending all components to the client and you decide which component to show based on the `user` object. There's a risk that if somebody edited the `user` object manually, then they would gain access to unauthorized routes.

The only way to be secure is to authenticate users on the server level and always make sure the server holds the authentication logic, not the client. I'd suggest that you implement separate pages for each type of user: `/student.js`, `/teacher.js` and `/admin.js` and redirect users to appropriate page based on the login result. Then, test on the server if the user has the authorization to view a particular route. This could be done in `getServerSideProps()`, e.g:

#### /pages/student.js

```js
export default function Student({ redirect }) {
  if (redirect) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <!-- render your page -->
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  /* Check the user status depending on your auth strategy */
  const user = req.session.get('user');

  /* Redirect to home route if user is not authenticated, or is not a 'student' type */
  if (!user || user.type !== 'student') {
    res.setHeader('Location', '/');
    res.statusCode = 302;
    return { props: { redirect: true } };
  }

  /* Proceed if authentication is successful */
  return { props: { } };
}
```